# ThirdPartyAddress contract error

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm trying to configure some protocols in Solidity (4.4 or olders) but I'm struggling right now an issue with the `[thirdPartyAddress]`. The code is the following:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
require(_value%100 == 0);
uint fee = _value/100;
require (balanceOf[msg.sender] > _value);
require (balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
balanceOf[_to] += (_value-fee);
balanceOf[thirdPartyAddress] += _value;
}
```

Error message is: **DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. balanceOf[thirdPartyAddress] += _value;**

Is there some suggestion to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thirdPartyAddress` is not declared, hence the error.

To solve the issue you could :

- declare `thirdPartyAddress` as a state variable and write a function to set it
- add `thirdPartyAddress` as a parameter of your function : `function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value, address thirdPartyAddress)`. However, note that in this case you will not follow the ERC20 interface anymore. So it may not be suitable.